# updateMany in mongodb where record = NaN to record = 0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, updates

So I have been reading how to do this operation on the command line and so far my command looks like

```
db.collection.updateMany( { mean: NaN }
```

but I am not sure what the rest of my command should be to set any field in my collection that is NaN to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to achieve your goal

```
db.collection.updateMany( { mean: NaN },{$set:{mean:0}})
```

Comment: Worked perfectly exactly what I needed. Thank you for being kind/polite! There are some mean nerds on here.

Comment: Lol you are welcome anytime there are also good people in community who are kind and helps every time